# Why can I successfully move a file in Linux while it is being written to?

Tags: java, android, linux, filesystems

I think this question  is technical enough for Stack Overflow and, probably, too programming-oriented for *Android*. I am intrigued as to how files are handled in Android (or Java or Linux, as appropriate), since I did something with my new smartphone and I'd curious to know how it happened.

I was transferring a file from my laptop to my Android phone via Bluetooth. I saw the new file in the file explorer and assumed it was fully transferred so I moved it from `/sdcard/bluetooth` to `/sdcard/torrents`. After I had done so, I noticed it was in fact still being transferred. To my surprise, it successfully completed, confirmed with a notification icon on the phone, and by a manual MD5 check on both sides. In most systems the file move would have caused a crash.

What is the reason for this successful transfer? I'm aware that in general, the file path is separate to the file location on the file system (in this case, an SD card). I imagine that the Bluetooth app has opened a handle to the file, and when I did the file move, a table of 'open files' was updated with a new path. Is this feature generally true of any Linux system? Could I do a `mv` on a file being written and expect the copy - in its new location - to be correct?

Comment: Why would moving files between two different file systems cause a crash to begin with?  The files themselves are kludges of binary data; the file system only represents how that kludge of data is stored, represented, and removed.

Comment: Moving a file in itself wouldn't be expected to cause a crash, but using `mv` on a file _whilst it is still being written to_ probably would (since in general a system that writes to a file should be able to assume that the file stays in the same location from write-opening to write-closing). I am trying to understand if the latter case holds true for all Linux (or Java, or Android) systems. Extra scout/brownie points for anyone who can explain why this succeeds!

Comment: @ain'tshabby: please don't edit posts here until you've had some practice with the platform. I've rejected the edit because it inverts the meaning of the title.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When you move a file **inside the same filesystem**, the file itself (the *inode*) isn't moved at all. The only thing that changes are the directory entries in that filesystem. (The system call invoked by `mv` in this case is [`rename(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/rename.2.html) - check that page for additional information and restrictions.)

When a process opens a file, the filename is passed to the OS to indicate which file is meant, but the file descriptor you get back isn't linked to that name at all (you can't get back a filename from it) – it is linked to the inode.
Since the inode remains unchanged when you rename a file (inside the same filesystem), processes that have it open can happily keep reading from and writing to it – nothing changed for them, their file descriptor is still valid and pointing to the right data.

Same thing if you delete a file. Processes can keep reading and writing from it even if the file is no longer reachable through any directory entry. (This can lead to confusing situations where `df` reports that your disk is full, but `du` says you're using much less space that `df` reports. The blocks assigned to deleted files that are still open won't be released until those processes close their file descriptor.)

If the `mv` moves the file across filesystems, then the behavior is different since inodes are specific to each filesystem. In that case, `mv` will actually copy the data over, creating a new inode (and directory entry) on the destination filesystem. When the copy is over, the old file is unlinked, and removed *if* there are no open filehandles on it, as above.
In your case, if you had crossed a filesystem boundary, you'd have a partial file in the destination. And your upload process happily writing to a deleted file you can't easily access, possibly filling up that filesystem, until the upload finished at which point the inode would get dropped.

Some posts on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) that you could find interesting:

- [How are directories implemented in Unix filesystems?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/how-are-directories-implemented-in-unix-filesystems)
- [What is a Superblock, Inode, Dentry and a File?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4402/what-is-a-superblock-inode-dentry-and-a-file)

Comment: Great answer, thank you Mat. Yes, I was moving the file inside the one file system. I've developed on Unix-like systems for some years, but not encountered this ability before; I'd have expected it to have upset the writer process. Pretty clever stuff!

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there ways to move a file between filesystems in a way that is transparent to applications, i.e. where the application can read, write and seek on top of a file descriptor while the underlying filesystem has changed?

Comment: @Witiko: not that I know of.