# How to check if a file is already opened (in the same process)

Tags: python, file-io, raspbian, python-3.5

And I'd like to specifically achieve that with the try catch construct.

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825994/check-if-a-file-is-open-in-python) suggests that I can do:

```
try:
    open(fileName, 'wb+')
except:
    print("File already opened!")
    raise
```

However, it doesn't work me. I can open the same file multiple times without any problem:

```
fileObj1 = open(fileName, 'wb+')
fileObj2 = open(fileName, 'wb+')
```

Is it because I have Python 3.5? Or because I'm using [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The reason I can open a file multiple times is because "only Windows locks files when open for writing. POSIX platforms do not.". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617452/opening-already-opened-file-does-not-raise-exception for more information.

Comment: If you are running in the same process how would you not know if the file is open?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have a script that imports an external library/module that can open and close a file. My script needs a way to know if the file is currently open or closed.

Comment: So you are not actually opening the file with `wb+`? That means reading an writing but it will truncate the data first, you would only read from it after you have written something and seek back

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What do you mean? I don't actually need to open the file in my script. In my question I'm doing it because I expected that it threw an error if the file was already open, thus letting me check if the file is open or closed.

Comment: I think you may have an xy problem,  if you add some context to you question it may help get a better answer

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Honestly, I think it's pretty clear. The two answers below specifically address the problem. I'm trying to "check if a file is already opened". My question shows what I have tried; `open` the file which I want to check is open or not and expect an error if the file has already been opened. Unfortunately, this doesn't work because my OS is a POSIX platform. I don't *need* to open the file, it's just one way to check if a file is open or not.

Comment: What happens if the file is already open?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You mean if I try to open a file that is already open? Nothing, I just get multiple file objects. As stated in my question "I can open the same file multiple times without any problem".

Comment: I mean in your code, how does knowing if a file is open or not affect the flow of your code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I need to move a file with `shutil.move`, but I don't want to do it if it's currently being written on/if it's open.

Comment: But that is not an issue at all in linux, the inode never moves, it is just the directory entries that change presuming you are on the same filesystem? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164577/is-it-safe-to-move-a-file-thats-being-appended-to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818802/why-can-i-successfully-move-a-file-in-linux-while-it-is-being-written-to

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well it's an issue, because in order to keep writing on that file after it has moved, you need a new file object. Any external library doesn't know if the file has moved or not, so it doesn't know it has to create another file object with the new location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should open the same file but assign them to different variables, like so:

```py
file_obj = open(filename, "wb+")

if not file_obj.closed:
    print("File is already opened")
```

The `.closed` only checks if the file has been opened by the same Python process.

Comment: This does not solve the OP's question? He is asking how to check if a specific file is open. `f=open(f_name, mode) != f_o=open(f_name, mode)` because `open()` returns an instance of some fileobj. Therefore `fileobj.closed` would always evaluate to `False` assuming you opened the file on the previous line?

Comment: Although this technique is less flexible and doesn't use the `try...except` construct, it isn't platform dependent and actually works. I don't know why it got downvoted.

Comment: @maximedupre I didn't downvote but I suspect it's b/c most people end up here b/c they're trying to figure out if a **different** process has the file open, which is a much more difficult problem.  But as your subject line notes, it's for the "same process" so this answer is 100% correct and shouldn't be downvoted, it's just not useful for most people  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using something like this

```
# Only works on Windows
def is_open(file_name):
    if os.path.exists(file_name):
        try:
            os.rename(file_name, file_name) #can't rename an open file so an error will be thrown
            return False
        except:
            return True
    raise NameError
```

Edited to fit the OP's specific issues

```
class FileObject(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.__file = None
        self.__locked = False

    @property
    def file(self):
        return self.__file

    @property
    def locked(self):
        return self.__locked

    def open(self, mode, lock=True):#any testing on file should go before the if statement such as os.path.exists()
        #replace mode with *args if you want to pass multiple modes
        if not self.locked:
            self.__locked = lock
            self.__file = open(self.file_name, mode)
            return self.file
        else:
            print 'Cannot open file because it has an exclusive lock placed on it'
            return None #do whatever you want to do if the file is already open here

    def close(self):
        if self.file != None:
            self.__file.close()
            self.__file = None
            self.__locked = False

    def unlock(self):
        if self.file != None:
            self.__locked = False
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm able to `rename` a file even if it's open. Perhaps because my OS is Raspbian?

Comment: Perhaps that lock is OS specific, if so then I would take a look at the Python open modes here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_open.htm and try `os.O_CREAT` and also `os.O_EXLOCK` or a combination. Let me know if this works on Raspbian. I assume it will because it is not os specific.

Comment: os.O_EXLOCK won't be available on a pi

Comment: Yeah, `os.O_EXLOCK` is not available on a Pi. When I try it, I get `AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'O_EXLOCK'`.

Comment: From the [Python 3.5 doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html): "The following constants are options for the flags parameter to the open() function. They can be combined using the bitwise OR operator |. Some of them are not available on all platforms.".

Comment: then I would create and share your own file obj. Look for my updated answer.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for that nifty custom file object class. It definitely works when you are the only one touching and maintaining the file, but in a context where there are third party libraries/modules in play, it's more complicated. For instance, I can't tell the library that creates the file that I want to check is open or not to use this custom file object class. I'm sure others will find this useful though.