# Python - test if a file has already been open

Tags: python, file

I would testing if a file has already been open before writing.

Here my code :

```
with open(file_five, 'w') as f:
    f.write(xml)
```

I would something as this code example :

```
if "file_five has already been open"
        with open(file_five, 'w') as f:
           f.write(xml)
else:
...
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'has been open' earlier opened by your script or ever before?

Comment: Yes. open by the script

Comment: In that case, possible duplicate of [How to check if a file is already opened (in the same process)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515574/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-already-opened-in-the-same-process)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca am not sure it's exactly the same problem. I think OP wants to know if the file has already been opened in the past, not if the file is  opened right now.... or i totally misunderstood :D

Comment: Does it make a difference? You overwrite the file anyhow ... truncating it in the process.

Comment: @flo I'd say the question is not clear, if that's the case. OP may want to clarify.

Comment: Using the `with open(..) as f: ... ` aproach it is quite easy to se if it is open (in your program) - it closes when you leave the scope of the `with ....:` context manager.

Comment: My question is testing if the file already been opened in the past

Comment: @PseudoWithK and is now closed? Just add a boolean and set it to `True` whenever you open the file, then check if it's `True` before opening again.

Answer (score -2):

There are two ways:
1-> **For Excel specific**

```
try:
    myfile = open("file_five.csv", "r+") # or "a+", whatever you need
except IOError:
    print "Could not open file! !"

with myfile:
    do_stuff()
```

2 -> For any file (**Rename approach**)

```
import os

try: 
    os.rename('file.xls', 'tempfile.xls')
    os.rename('tempfile.xls', 'file.xls')
except OSError:
    print('File is still open.')
```